# Laravel 5.6 deploy project to sharing host gets HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, server

i deployed and uploaded my laravel 5.6 project on my sharing host but it gives me `HTTP 500 ERROR`. what is wrong! in index.php I've changed the required path but it still gives me that error! **IT WORKS PERFECTLY ON MY LOCAL MACHINE**!

Comment: try this tutorial https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

Comment: check this pages in search answer your problem: https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6 and https://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting

Comment: This can sometimes occur if permissions for the index.php are not set correctly. Do you have SSH access?

Comment: @Ross unfortunately not. i think it's for the php version! laravel doc says that it should be > 7.1 and mine is 7.0.3

Comment: That will definitely be a problem. If you don't have ssh access how are you able to install your dependences? Are you just transferring all of the files with FTP?

Comment: Yeah. i saw some people doing it and it would be fine! i send the requirement list to the my host and they said that they already installed all of them but PHP version is 7.0.3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was for the PHP version. according to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) the PHP version should be over 7.1. mine was 7.0.3 . i updated my PHP version to 7.2 and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://vrgl.ir/heOGf)

I hope it would solve your problem, keep in mind if you don't have `cache.php` file in your project you should run below command to generate one to be able to reconfigure it to be able to load your project on sharing host.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**update**

Make sure your index.php file which should be in public_html is similar to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../subtitle/bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../subtitle/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: i send ticket to the host and the replied:

Comment: کاربر گرامی،

سرور با خطای زیر از یاب دامنه شما مواجه می گردد. لطفا بررسی فرمایید:

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: require(/home/amirmeim/domains/amirmeimari.ir/public_html/lab/submore/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/amirmeim/domains/amirmeimari.ir/public_html/lab/submore/index.php on line 24\nPHP message

این مسیر به نظر وجود ندارد: /domains/amirmeimari.ir/public_html/lab/submore/../vendor/autoload.php

Comment: but here is my require: `require __DIR__.'/../subtitle/vendor/autoload.php';
` and `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../subtitle/bootstrap/app.php';
`

Comment: your project name is subtitle? is it in in the root directory alongside public_html?

Comment: @AmirMeimari Check out the update that i made in my answer

Comment: yeah it is. i think it's for the php version. mine is currently 7.0.3 but the laravel doc said that it should be + 7.1.3 .

Comment: It could be the problem, which version of laravel you're using?

Comment: 5.6 . Thank it was for the PHP version. i updated mine to 7.2 and problem solved. but i;m curious why this question got -2 :|

Comment: @AmirMeimari it's because your topic is too general and you didn't explain the exact problem, like what's your local environment configuration and what's your host provider configuration.